# How to detect a record is locked too long?

Tags: java, oracle, algorithm, struts2, spring-mybatis

I was recently asked this question at work.

There are some records in db(database). Example, we have recordA, recordB, ....

[Stock Management] Screen display the constents of them.

There are some user. We have userA, userB, ...

***The records in db.***

```
recordId ...userId....  status(locked=1, unlocked=0)
--------------------------
recordA     userA       0
recordA     userB       0
recordB     userA       0
recordB     userB       0
...
```

userA login system, click on recordA in [Stock Management] screen for editing, the status of recordA is 'locked'.

***The status of record A in db***.

```
recordId ...userId....  status(locked=1, unlocked=0)
--------------------------
recordA     userA       1
recordA     userB       0
recordB     userA       0
recordB     userB       0
...
```

At present, userB can't change recordA. When userB click on recordA, it'll show err message "***recordA is locked***"

And now I need to implement this logic "***After 60 second from userA click on recordA, if user don't send any requests to server. userB can click on recordA for editing***"

**Framework:** Struts2, Spring-ibatis, Oracle db, Java.

**And this is my solution:**

1. When userA enters the screen and lock recordA, set the timestamp in
   a static Map: `Map<String, Long> timeUsers = <userId, System timestamp>`
2. Every time users(userA, userB, ...) send a request to server, update or set timestamp with each userId.
3. UserB enters the screen and see the status of recordA is locked. UserB click on recordA,

   I'll check: time userB click on record A - time userA is kept in static Map

   ```
     If(time userB click on recordA - time userA is kept in Map<String, Long> 
       )> 60 (s){

       - Update db. Change status of recordA(1->0) with userA
       - Update db. Change status of recordA(0->1) with userB
     } 

    db is updated

    recordId ...userId....  status(locked=1, unlocked=0)
    --------------------------
    recordA        userA       0
    recordA        userB       1
    recordB        userA       0
    recordB        userB       0
   ```

But I think it's not so good. UserA cannot see status of recordA has changed. Keep value in static variables...

Anyone have another solution for this?

Comment: When A clicks, why don't you start a timer that unlocks A after one minute ?

Comment: There is this handly class in Java called `ScheduledExecutorService`. Take a look.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If user sends requests to server in 60s. You need to check in server.
And if userA click on record A, after that, click on recordB, too many timer.

Comment: @Noname: the lock and the timer are started on the server. (And if A unlocks prematurely, the timer should be killed.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If user A send a request in 60s. Timer always need to be reset.
what happen if we have a lot of timer when user lock successfully a record. I think it's is complex

Comment: @noname: only one user can lock, so at any time there's only one active timer (per locked record).

Answer (score 0):

Anything on the client side is bad as it can crash and won't work if you scale out. Replace `status` 1/0 with `locked_until_ts`. Optionally add a `locked_by` so that B can talk to A. It is impossible to grab a lock from someone else (but OK to grab it from yourself) until the lock has expired. You may want to add a version column for optimistic locking at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the timestamp of each action of a user in your database for this purpose instead of status. Whenever someone loads the user, if the information whether the user is clickable or not can be gathered. Basically you load the timestamp along the user information and see whether it was in the last 60 seconds. If so, then you do not even need to send a request to the server if user tries to click to the other user. If the time elapsed, then you will need to request the timestamp from the server and see whether the user is clickable, or another action was done by him or her since the last check. Also, if a user was loaded as clickable, when another user clicks on the user, you will need to check this timestamp, just to make sure that the other user did not do anything in the last 60 seconds.